# How do I add class "caption" into image?

Tags: media

I using image field with insert module to upload image.
After select an image and upload, I press "insert".
The image appears in body but the script of image doesn't have class "caption".

```
<img src="/sites/default/files/apple.jpg" title="Some description image here" height="260" width="500">
```

How do I add class "caption" into image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option in the Insert section of the field to add classes. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: @user73963 he is  yourself !! :)))

Answer (score -1):

For adding caption to image there is some module

[Image Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption)

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> This module uses JQuery to dynamically add captions to images. The
>   image title attribute is used to create the caption. It basically
>   wraps the image in an html container div, takes the image title text
>   and appends that in a child div underneath the image. Technically, it
>   works by implementing Drupal's hook_nodeapi to add one small snippet
>   of captioner jquery to the head section of the page when a node of the
>   configured type is viewed.

[Image Field Caption](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_caption)

> Description: Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.
>
> Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image
>   field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html
>   descriptions of an image.

[JCaption](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcaption)

> Description: This is a simple module for Drupal 7.x that uses jQuery
>   to transform the TITLE or ALT attribute of a image to a image caption.
>   There is a settings page with lot's of possible configuration. The
>   image caption won't show in the WYSIWYG-editor, but will be visible
>   when you view the node.
>
> The module differs in several ways from similar modules.

Comment: I don't see how any of these address the OP's question which is to 'add class "caption" into image?'  Before posting the same answer to multiple questions, please make sure you tailor them to the individual needs.  If they are truly the same vote/flag as a duplicate.

Comment: @MPD  I thinks some misunderstanding happened here, ok ;)